# How to create a string from bits?

Tags: c#

I used the following method to create bits from a string, but now I am trying to do the reverse and I can't figure out how to do it?

```
public string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input))
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I want to pass in the string of bits and create the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GetBits method doesn't work properly - it doesn't convert 8 bits for every byte.

As a crude fix, you can use PadLeft. Here's the complete solution:

```
// Fixed version of GetBits, with padding.
public static string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input))
    {
        string lowBits = Convert.ToString(b, 2);
        string eightBits = lowBits.PadLeft(8, '0');
        sb.Append(eightBits);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string UnicodeBitsToString(string input)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ParseHex(input));
}

public static byte[] ParseHex(string input)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[input.Length/8];
    for (int i=0; i < input.Length; i += 8)
    {
        ret[i/8] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i, 8), 2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It's a bit nasty though - I'm positive you could make it more efficient. Still, if it does what you need it to do...

Comment: Thanks Jon, Can you elaborate a little more. I tested with the word "cat" and I got 24 bits which is what I expected.

Comment: You shouldn't have expected to get 24 bits - "cat" is three characters; each character in Encoding.Unicode takes 2 bytes = 16 bits so you should have seen 48 bits. Basically you got lucky because the 7th bit was always set and the other byte was always 0. Try it was a space...

Comment: If you only want to deal with ASCII, you can halve the space taken by using Encoding.ASCII instead of Encoding.Unicode in the code I've given. That *would* give you 24 bits for "cat".

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use <s>hex</s> binary? Things will be a bit easier (and shorter, length-wise) if you use base-64:

```
        string s = "abcdefg";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
        string s1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
```

Comment: I can't use HEX, so if I pass in "11000110", I expect the letter "C".

Comment: Xaisoft: Why would you expect "C"? "11000110" is 198 in decimal, which isn't "C" in any encoding I know of. Did you mean "01100011"?

Answer (score 1):

Convert::ToInt64 Method (String, Int32)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk8t68tb.aspx)